# Fastest way to expand a time series by specified time lengths in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, lapply, posixct

I have a data from two types of activity loggers. The first logger records the number of seconds the logger is in a wet or dry state (see **act1**). The second logger samples for wet/dry every 3 seconds and makes a record of the total number of samples wet every 10 minutes. Given the sampling interval of 3 seconds, the value recorded at the end of each 10 minute period ranges from zero (always dry) to 200 (always wet), see **act2**.

I would like to reshape and resample the data from the first logger to replicate the format of the second logger using the most efficient method possible.

The example I have provided here uses a subsample of the data (6 rows), however my actual dataset consists of over a year of observations (40,000+ rows) and at the moment is still running after 3 days.

```
act1 <- structure(list(
Valid = c("ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok"),
Date = structure(c(1425579093, 1425579171, 1425579177, 1425579216, 1425579225, 1425579240),
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
Activity = c(78L, 6L, 39L, 9L, 15L, 9L),
Wet = c("wet", "dry", "wet", "dry", "wet", "dry")),
row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
class = "data.frame")

act2 <- structure(list(
Valid = c("ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok"),
Date = structure(c(1425579093, 1425579171, 1425579177, 1425579216, 1425579225, 1425579240),
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
Activity = c(78L, 6L, 39L, 9L, 15L, 9L),
Wet = c("wet", "dry", "wet", "dry", "wet", "dry")), row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
class = "data.frame")
```

Using **lapply** I have expanded the *Date* column (POSIXct format) in the **act1** dataframe based on intervals specified in the *Activity* column and kept the reference to the corresponding state in the *Wet* column.

```
act1  <-  lapply(1:nrow(act1),  function(x){
  data.frame(
    Valid = rep(act1[x, 1], act1[x, 3]), 
    Date = strptime(act1[x, 2], format = "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")+(seq_len(act1[x, 3])-1), 
    Activity = rep(1, act1[x, 3]), 
    Wet = rep(act1[x, 4], act1[x, 3])
  )})
act1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, act1))
```

I have then use **dplyr** and **lubridate** to group each observation into 3 second bins and determine whether the last observation in each bin is wet. I group the remaining wet observations 10 minute bins and summarise how many samples are wet.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

act1 <- act1 %>%
  mutate(interval = floor_date(Date, unit="minutes") + seconds(floor(second(Date)/3)*3)) %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>%
  summarise(Valid = "ok",
            Wet = Wet[which(Date==max(Date))]=="wet") %>%
  mutate(int10 = floor_date(interval, unit="hour") +
           minutes(floor(minute(interval)/10)*10) +
           (min(interval) - min(floor_date(interval, unit="hour") + minutes(floor(minute(interval)/10)*10)))) %>% 
  group_by(int10) %>%
  summarise(Valid = "ok",
            Activity = sum(Wet)) %>%
  rename(Date = int10) %>%
  select(Valid,Date,Activity)
```

The example I have provided here uses a subset of the original dataset (6 rows), however my actual dataset consists of over a year of observations (40,000+ rows) and at the moment is **still running after 3 days!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorization, `rep`, `cut`, and `seq` should be in your tool box for this task.

Your first main statement involving the `lapply` can be shortened - you're just trying to repeat the rows. For instance, `act1[c(1,1), ]` will return the first row of `act1` 2 times. In your loop, you access `act1[x, 3]`  4 times. This one line below will copy the rows we want the number of times we need:

```
act1a <- act1_copy[rep(seq_len(nrow(act1_copy)), act1_copy[['Activity']]), ]

> nrow(act1_copy)
[1] 6
> seq_len(nrow(act1_copy))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> act1_copy[['Activity']]
[1] 78  6 39  9 15  9
> rep(seq_len(nrow(act1_copy)), act1_copy[['Activity']])
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [60] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[119] 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

# or if you're into external packages, this is a lot nicer looking:
tidyr::uncount(act1_copy, weights = Activity)
```

The next step is to correct the seconds and to redo the `Activity` to `1`.

```
act1a[['Date']] <- act1a[['Date']] + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1
act1a[['Activity']] <- 1L
```

Now the last step to have the old logging data match the newer logging data (i.e., a log once every 3 seconds), is to group by 3 seconds. It's important to note that once every 3 seconds is equivalent to once every 3 rows. So depending on how confident that `act$Date` is complete, we can do one of two methods:

```
act1b <- act1a[!duplicated(cut(act1a$Date, '3 sec', labels = F)), ]

# or if you're sure there is one reading per second, you can just do once every three rows 
act1b <- act1a[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1a), by = 3), ]

# what cut() looks like for reference
cut(act1a$Date, '3 sec', labels = F)
  [1]  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5  6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10 11 11 11 12 12 12 13 13 13
 [40] 14 14 14 15 15 15 16 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 21 21 21 22 22 22 23 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 25 26 26 26
 [79] 27 27 27 28 28 28 29 29 29 30 30 30 31 31 31 32 32 32 33 33 33 34 34 34 35 35 35 36 36 36 37 37 37 38 38 38 39 39 39
[118] 40 40 40 41 41 41 42 42 42 43 43 43 44 44 44 45 45 45 46 46 46 47 47 47 48 48 48 49 49 49 50 50 50 51 51 51 52 52 52

#or with labels:
cut(act1a$Date, '3 sec')
  [1] 2015-03-05 13:11:33 2015-03-05 13:11:33 2015-03-05 13:11:33 2015-03-05 13:11:36 2015-03-05 13:11:36
  [6] 2015-03-05 13:11:36 2015-03-05 13:11:39 2015-03-05 13:11:39 2015-03-05 13:11:39 2015-03-05 13:11:42
 [11] 2015-03-05 13:11:42 2015-03-05 13:11:42 2015-03-05 13:11:45 2015-03-05 13:11:45 2015-03-05 13:11:45
 [16] 2015-03-05 13:11:48 2015-03-05 13:11:48 2015-03-05 13:11:48 2015-03-05 13:11:51 2015-03-05 13:11:51
 [21] 2015-03-05 13:11:51 2015-03-05 13:11:54 2015-03-05 13:11:54 2015-03-05 13:11:54 2015-03-05 13:11:57 
# truncated for brevity.
```

The last step is to aggregate the data. Just like with the last step, we can either use `cut()` to group using times or we can use `rep(seq())` again to make our groupings a little faster.

```
aggregate(act1b$Wet, list(Date = cut(act1b$Date, '10 min')), FUN = function(x) sum(x == 'wet'))
#or if you know there is one reading per second,
aggregate(act1b$Wet,
          list(Date = rep(act1b$Date[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1b), by = 10 * 60 / 3)]
                          , each = 10 * 60 / 3
                          , length.out = nrow(act1b)))
               , FUN = function(x) sum(x == 'wet'))
```

Putting it all together, you get:

```
act1a <- act1_copy[rep(seq_len(nrow(act1_copy)), act1_copy[['Activity']]), ]
act1a[['Date']] <- act1a[['Date']] + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1
act1a[['Activity']] <- 1L

act1b <- act1a[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1a), by = 3), ]

aggregate(act1b$Wet,
          list(Date = rep(act1b$Date[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1b), by = 10 * 60 / 3)]
                          , each = 10 * 60 / 3
                          , length.out = nrow(act1b)))
               , FUN = function(x) sum(x == 'wet'))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
  tidyr::uncount(act1_copy, weights = Activity)%>%
    mutate(Activity = 1L
           , Date = Date + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1)%>%
    slice(seq(from = 1, to = nrow(.), by = 3))%>%
    group_by(Date =rep(Date[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(.), by = 10 * 60 / 3)]
                           , each = 10 * 60 / 3
                           , length.out = nrow(.)))%>%
    summarize(Wet = sum(Wet == 'wet'))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Date                  Wet
  <dttm>              <int>
1 2015-03-05 13:11:33    44
```

Are are some performance and code - note the `data.table` way I had issues with the 10 minute summarizing so it is not completely apples to apples:

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    cole_base  2.044400  2.174451  2.328061  2.253251  2.340801  6.424400   100
   cole_dplyr  3.152901  3.359501  3.502880  3.428101  3.515302  8.248401   100
      cole_dt  3.308601  3.541151  3.884475  3.698201  3.796652 13.155701   100
 original_all 32.626601 33.061152 34.531462 33.392151 34.237601 50.499501   100
```

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

act1_copy <- structure(list(
  Valid = c("ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok"),
  Date = structure(c(1425579093, 1425579171, 1425579177, 1425579216, 1425579225, 1425579240),
                   class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
  Activity = c(78L, 6L, 39L, 9L, 15L, 9L),
  Wet = c("wet", "dry", "wet", "dry", "wet", "dry")),
  row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
  class = "data.frame")

dt <- as.data.table(act1_copy)
microbenchmark( cole_base = {
  act1a <- act1_copy[rep(seq_len(nrow(act1_copy)), act1_copy[['Activity']]), ]
  act1a[['Date']] <- act1a[['Date']] + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1
  # if you know there is definitly one reading per second
  # act1a[['Date']] <- act1a[['Date']] + seq_len(nrow(act1a)) - 1
  act1a[['Activity']] <- 1L

  # act1b <- act1a[!duplicated(cut(act1a$Date, '3 sec', labels = F)), ]
  # or if you're sure there is one reading per second, you can just do once every three rows 
  act1b <- act1a[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1a), by = 3), ]

  # aggregate(act1b$Wet, list(Date = cut(act1b$Date, '10 min')), FUN = function(x) sum(x == 'wet'))
  #or if you know there is one reading per second,
  aggregate(act1b$Wet,
            list(Date = rep(act1b$Date[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(act1b), by = 10 * 60 / 3)]
                            , each = 10 * 60 / 3
                            , length.out = nrow(act1b)))
                 , FUN = function(x) sum(x == 'wet'))

}
, cole_dplyr = {
  tidyr::uncount(act1_copy, weights = Activity)%>%
    mutate(Activity = 1L
           , Date = Date + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1)%>%
    # filter(!duplicated(cut(Date, '3 sec', labels = F)))%>%
    slice(seq(from = 1, to = nrow(.), by = 3))%>%
    # group_by(Date = cut(Date, '10 min'))%>%
    group_by(Date =rep(Date[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(.), by = 10 * 60 / 3)]
                           , each = 10 * 60 / 3
                           , length.out = nrow(.)))%>%
    summarize(Wet = sum(Wet == 'wet'))

}
, cole_dt = {
  copy(dt)[rep(seq_len(.N), Activity)
           , .(Date = Date + sequence(act1_copy[['Activity']]) - 1
               ,Wet, Valid, Activity = 1L) 
           ][seq(from = 1, to = .N, by = 3)
             , .(Wet = sum(Wet == 'wet'))
             , by = cut(Date, '10 min')]
}
, original_all = {
  act1  <-  lapply(1:nrow(act1_copy),  function(x){
    data.frame(
      Valid = rep(act1_copy[x, 1], act1_copy[x, 3]),
      Date = strptime(act1_copy[x, 2], format = "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")+(seq_len(act1_copy[x, 3])-1),
      Activity = rep(1, act1_copy[x, 3]),
      Wet = rep(act1_copy[x, 4], act1_copy[x, 3])
    )})
  act1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, act1))

  act1 <- act1 %>%
    mutate(interval = floor_date(Date, unit="minutes") + seconds(floor(second(Date)/3)*3)) %>%
    group_by(interval) %>%
    summarise(Valid = "ok",
              Wet = Wet[which(Date==max(Date))]=="wet") %>%
    mutate(int10 = floor_date(interval, unit="hour") +
             minutes(floor(minute(interval)/10)*10) +
             (min(interval) - min(floor_date(interval, unit="hour") + minutes(floor(minute(interval)/10)*10)))) %>%
    group_by(int10) %>%
    summarise(Valid = "ok",
              Activity = sum(Wet)) %>%
    rename(Date = int10) %>%
    select(Valid,Date,Activity)
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Cole, the improvement in processing time is incredible!

Comment: If it worked, you should accept the answer as a solution and upvote.

Comment: Done! Thank-you.